# Aggregate data by groups of elements

Tags: python, group-by, find, aggregate

I have 2 files:
First looks like this:

```
ID1;ID2;ID3;VALUE  
1000;100;01;12
1000;100;02;4129
1000;100;03;128
1000;100;04;412
1000;100;05;12818
1000;100;06;4129
1000;100;07;546
1000;100;08;86
1000;100;09;12818
1000;100;10;754
1000;100;11;2633
1000;100;12;571
1000;200;01;13
1000;200;02;319
1000;200;03;828
1000;200;04;46
1000;200;05;118
1000;200;06;41
1000;200;07;546
1000;200;08;86
1000;200;09;129
1000;200;10;7564
1000;200;11;233
1000;200;12;572
```

The second one looks like this:

```
01

01
02

01
02
03

01
02
03
04
....
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

I want to search through the first file, using the groups from the second one, and then sum up de values.
The output should look like this:

```
ID1;ID2;ID3;VALUE
1000;100;M01;12
1000;100;M02;4141 (12+4129)
1000;100;M03;4269
---
1000;100;M12;39036

1000;200;M01;13
1000;200;M02;332
```

Is there any way to do this? Thank you in advance, any idea is welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried? Is there a specific problem?

Comment: @TedroyG how should the search be performed in the second file: is it just the presence of elements or by indexes (for example, for the first search, these are indexes from 1 to 12 from the first file)? If by indexes are spaces between lines taken into account?

Comment: Hi @inquirer it is by indexes, and the spaces are not taken into account. Basically when it finds a space, it should rerun the code using the next block of data

Comment: @TedroyG check if it's not what you expected. Show all expected output, based on your frames.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.txt', sep =';', header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.txt', header=None)
df1['preliminary'] = 0
df1['test'] = 0
print(df1)
print(df2)

aaa = df2.index[-1]


def my_func(x):
    ind = x.index[x.index > aaa]
    bbb = 0
    if len(ind) > 0:
        bbb = df2[x.index[0]:ind[0]]
    else:
        bbb = df2[x.index[0]:x.index[-1]+1]

    indGR = x[x['ID3'].isin(bbb[0].values)].index
    df1.loc[indGR, 'preliminary'] = df1.loc[indGR, 'VALUE']
    df1.loc[x.index,'test'] = df1.loc[x.index, 'preliminary'].cumsum()

df1.groupby('ID2').apply(my_func)

print(df1)
```

Input

```
 ID1  ID2  ID3  VALUE    preliminary  test
0   1000  100    1       12            0     0
1   1000  100    2     4129            0     0
2   1000  100    3      128            0     0
3   1000  100    4      412            0     0
4   1000  100    5    12818            0     0
5   1000  100    6     4129            0     0
6   1000  100    7      546            0     0
7   1000  100    8       86            0     0
8   1000  100    9    12818            0     0
9   1000  100   10      754            0     0
10  1000  100   11     2633            0     0
11  1000  100   12      571            0     0
12  1000  200    1       13            0     0
13  1000  200    2      319            0     0
14  1000  200    3      828            0     0
15  1000  200    4       46            0     0
16  1000  200    5      118            0     0
17  1000  200    6       41            0     0
18  1000  200    7      546            0     0
19  1000  200    8       86            0     0
20  1000  200    9      129            0     0
21  1000  200   10     7564            0     0
22  1000  200   11      233            0     0
23  1000  200   12      572            0     0
     0
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    4
10   1
11   2
12   3
13   4
14   5
15   6
16   7
17   8
18   9
19  10
20  11
21  12
```

Output

```
     ID1  ID2  ID3  VALUE    preliminary   test
0   1000  100    1       12           12     12
1   1000  100    2     4129         4129   4141
2   1000  100    3      128          128   4269
3   1000  100    4      412          412   4681
4   1000  100    5    12818            0   4681
5   1000  100    6     4129            0   4681
6   1000  100    7      546            0   4681
7   1000  100    8       86            0   4681
8   1000  100    9    12818            0   4681
9   1000  100   10      754            0   4681
10  1000  100   11     2633            0   4681
11  1000  100   12      571            0   4681
12  1000  200    1       13            0      0
13  1000  200    2      319            0      0
14  1000  200    3      828          828    828
15  1000  200    4       46           46    874
16  1000  200    5      118          118    992
17  1000  200    6       41           41   1033
18  1000  200    7      546          546   1579
19  1000  200    8       86           86   1665
20  1000  200    9      129          129   1794
21  1000  200   10     7564         7564   9358
22  1000  200   11      233          233   9591
23  1000  200   12      572          572  10163
```